# Considering $\epsilon$ intuitively in limit proof

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I'm having rather difficult time in trying to use $\epsilon$ argument appropriately.

For example here is my simple $\epsilon$ proof in one question. The question is as follow: Prove if $s_n \geq 0$ for $n \geq k$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n = s$ exist, then $s \geq 0$.

My try:

We know $s_n \geq 0$ and according to the limit definition, for each $\epsilon >0$ there exist $n$ such that $| s_n - s | < \epsilon$ for $n \geq N$. We consider the case where $s_n - s > 0$, thus $s > s_n - \epsilon$. But we can find any $\epsilon$ and $n$ such that $s_n - \epsilon \geq 0$. Thus $s > s_n - \epsilon \geq 0$. For the second case, if $s_n - s < 0$ and $s_n \geq 0$ then $s \geq 0$.

Is this the right way to use $\epsilon$, that is, treating it as arbitrary positive number that can be chosen so that we can have the desired inequality, as long as that inequality is derived from limit definition?

Answer (score 2):

If we use the $\epsilon-N$ definition, because $\lim_n s_n=s$, so for any $\epsilon >0$, there  exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$, we have $|s_n-s|<\epsilon$, so $s>s_n-\epsilon \geq -\epsilon$.

Notice that $s>-\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon >0$, so we must have $s\geq 0$.

Comment: Do we need to consider the case where $s_n - s < 0$ for the absolute value inequality in the proof?

Comment: No, you need not to consider whether $s_n$ is bigger than $s$ or not. Form $|s_n-s|<\epsilon$, we can get $s_n-\epsilon <s < s_n +\epsilon$ and $s>s_n-\epsilon$ is what we want because the condition is $s_n\geq 0$, they have the same direction of inequlity.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot find $n$ such that $s_n - \epsilon \geq 0$. Not if $s_n = 0$.

What you need to use is that if $s < 0$ then there is a large gap between $s$ and any of the $s_n$. Suppose $s = -\epsilon$. Then for no $n$ do we have $|s_n - s| < \epsilon/2$.

Comment: Why it is so? Is it because $s_n < -\epsilon / 2$? (Contradicting the assumption) Also why do we need a factor of a half there?

Comment: @vonTeslacx, $|s_n-s| = s_n+\epsilon \geq \epsilon$. We don't really need a factor of half. It's only there to emphasize that *some* small number fits in the gap.

Comment: Ok so intuitively the assumption fails because of the existence of a gap between the final limit and the term that cannot be reduced by adjusting $s_n$?

Comment: @vonTeslacx, right.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you would like to see but I think I would rather prove this by contradiction.

Suppose $s < 0$ and that $|s| > \varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$. Thus there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq \mbox{max}(N,k)$, $|s - s_n| < \varepsilon$. Therefore $s_n < 0$ for all $n \geq N$. A contradiction.